# Delete cookies with a set path and name

Tags: javascript

Magento + Fastly CDN generates and sets cookies for GeoIP Redirects, where you get redirected once, then never again.

I want to do some cache busting, and if those cookies exist, then delete them, so the redirect *does* happen.

This is what Fastly sets:

```
# geoip lookup
    if (req.url.path ~ "fastlyCdn/geoip/getaction/") {
        # check if GeoIP has been already processed by client. this normally happens before essential cookies are set.
        if (req.http.cookie:X-Magento-Vary || req.http.cookie:form_key || req.http.cookie:fastly_geo_store) {
            error 980 "GeoIP already processed";
        } else {
            # append parameter with country code only if it doesn't exist already
            if ( req.url.qs !~ "country_code=" ) {
                set req.url = querystring.set(req.url, "country_code", if ( req.http.geo_override, req.http.geo_override, client.geo.country_code));
            }
        }
```

The URL Path is `"fastlyCdn/geoip/getaction/`" the names of the cookies are `X-Magento-Vary`, `form_key` and `fastly_geo_store`

What I want to do is simply clear these on full page load every time the page is loaded, if they exist.

Thank you.

I've tried writing some code that will clear all cookies, but it is not specific enough, and is overly broad.